# Perforce sync symlinks error on a jenkins windons agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce, jenkins-pipeline

I having trouble syncing my workspace on a Jenkins widows agent, do you know what is happening? Here is the error:

`ERROR: P4 Task: failed: com.perforce.p4java.exception.P4JavaException: com.perforce.p4java.exception.P4JavaException: hudson.AbortException: P4JAVA: Error(s):
symlink file C:\Jenkins\workspace\**\***** can't be sync'd or created with this client program.`

My setup:
Jenkins 2.74 (p4 plugin version: 2.7.3
windows 10 (with java 8 and p4 cmd installed)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the plugin might have been built with an old JDK?

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4javanotes.txt

```
* For Java versions prior to JDK 7, P4Java does not correctly
  implement or deal with Unix / Linux and Windows symbolic links.
  This is a known issue related to older (prior to JDK 7) versions
  of Java's inability to itself implement symbolic links.
```

Comment: Thks @Sam, but the issue was windows related, only admin was allowed to perform the symlink creation

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, it was a window related issue with symlinks creation, only admin was authorize to perform this action, either use admin account or through the security settings allow symlink creation by other users.